# How to join SELECT queries

Tags: sql-server

I have three queries as given below:

```
select sum(prod) as Production ,sum(rej) as Rejection 
where machinename='A' from data

select sum(prod) as Production ,sum(rej) as Rejection 
where machinename='B' from data 

select sum(prod) as Production ,sum(rej) as Rejection 
where machinename='C' from data
```

and I want to join these queries to get single row output.

Comment: `from tablename` should be before `where` condition.

Comment: Really this question deserves an upvote.

Comment: What columns do you expect to get the single row output?

Comment: @Manisha Parulekar do not forget to accept correct answer for future users, If any of solution helped for you

Answer (score 2):

First of all you have incorrect syntax. It should be

```
SELECT ....
FROM ....
WHERE ....
```

If you have 3 different source tables you can use `UNION` to get single output in following:

```
select sum(prod) as Production ,sum(rej) as Rejection 
from data1 
where machinename='A'

union -- or you can use UNION ALL to keep duplicates

select sum(prod) as Production ,sum(rej) as Rejection 
from data2 
where machinename='B'

union -- or you can use UNION ALL to keep duplicates

select sum(prod) as Production ,sum(rej) as Rejection 
from data3 
where machinename='C'
```

If you have the same source table as in example you an use `IN`

```
select sum(prod) as Production ,sum(rej) as Rejection 
from data3 
where machinename IN ('A','B','C')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select sum(CASE WHEN machinename='A' THEN prod END) as Production_A 
      ,sum(CASE WHEN machinename='A' THEN rej  END) as Rejection_A
      ,sum(CASE WHEN machinename='B' THEN prod END) as Production_B 
      ,sum(CASE WHEN machinename='B' THEN rej  END) as Rejection_B
      ,sum(CASE WHEN machinename='C' THEN prod END) as Production_C 
      ,sum(CASE WHEN machinename='C' THEN rej  END) as Rejection_C
from data
where machinename IN ('A','B','C')
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `IN`.

**Query**

```
select sum(prod) as Production,
sum(rej) as Rejection
from data
where machinename in ('A','B','C');
```

Answer (score 0):

try the following :

```
SELECT 
  sum(prod) as Production ,
  sum(rej) as Rejection 
FROM
  data
WHERE
  machinename='A' or
  machinename='B' or
  machinename='C'
```